# Who should handle events in case of a huge list of items

Tags: backbone.js

Consider following scenario:

```
<ListView>
     <ItemView>
         <div class="ticket-id">136</div>
         <div class="ticket-label">Hello everyone</div>
     </ItemView>
     <ItemView></ItemView>
     ... 500+ item views
</ListView>
```

Each item view have corresponding model. ListView creates itself by iterating through a collection of items and creating new ItemView.

The question is - who should handle events on items?

It's very logical and nice to have it on each ItemView itself. This way we have access to the model. But as we have tons and tons of items it means we will have same number of handlers - might be a problem.
Another way is to handle it on ListView level but this way we will have look inside DOM to check ticket-id for example and don't have access to the model.

Update: another issue is correctly removing such a view. If we use event handlers on ItemViews then we need to store them to later on remove each one. In case there is nothing on them - they should be garbaged collected automatically as they gave us nothing but a html string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not actually seeing performance problems, I wouldn't over-optimize. Have `ItemView` handle the events, because that's what makes sense.

If you already have known performance / memory issues, or you run into one down the line, then a combination of your two options might be the way to go: Have `ItemView` *handle* the events, but *listen* to the events in the parent `ListView`. This would require you to keep track of of your child views

So if your `ItemView` currently looks something like this:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click .submit" : "onSubmitClicked"
    },

    onSubmitClicked: function() {
        //...
    }
});
```

You could refactor it like this:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //give item a css class to scope the events
    cssClass: "item-view",

    initialize: function() {
        //set id attribute to the DOM element
        this.attributes["data-id"] = this.model.id;
    },
    onSubmitClicked: function() {
        //...
    }
});
```

And listen to the bubbled events in the list view, and proxy them to the item view:

```
var Listview = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        //scope child events by css class
        "click .item-view .submit" : "onItemSubmitClicked"
    },
    render function() {
        var childViews = this._childViews = {};

        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            //render the child views any way you want
            var itemView = new ItemView({model:model}).render();

            //keep a id->view map
            childViews[model.id] = itemView;
        });
    },
    //proxy events to the correct childview
    onItemSubmitClicked: function(event) {
        var itemView = this._childViews[$(event.target).attr('data-id')];
        itemView.onSubmitClicked(event);
    }
});
```

I've refactored existing views this way quite painlessly because the event handlers remain as they were before, and only the listener code gets moved up a notch. It does come with a complexity overhead, but if you need to optimize for performance, something usually has to give.

Comment: Very nice and interesting! And I also need to track item views as it possible for whole view to be closed so I need to cleanup. You help me yet again, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You bring up good points. If I were you (I've done lists a list of a 100 items with several event handlers with no problem) I'd go with the logical one where the ItemView handles the events.

I wouldn't pre optimize and make your code more complicated until you know its a problem.